# Manifest for native messaging host not found

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently trying to establish a connection between a chrome-extension and a NativeMessagingHost. Everything works fine on Windows, but it won't do on Linux (either arch, kali or ubuntu). 
How it fails:

> Can't find manifest for native messaging host my_host.json

### My current state:

- have my host manifest under `~/.config/google-chrome-beta/NativeMessagingHosts/my_host.json`

  - in there: `"name":"my_host.json"` and the path to my python script which handles the messages, also the unique chrome-extension code unter `allowed_origins`
- in `manifest.json` of my extension given the permission for `nativeMessaging`
- furthermore in `popup.js: var port = chrome.runtime.connectNative("my_host.json");` and the same name used in `sendNativeMessage`

### What I tried so far:

- tried with google-chrome-beta and -stable
- deleted file endings e.g. `my_host.json` to `my_host`, or removing the python ending
- easier paths where my python script lays
- also tried to put `my_host` into `/Library/Google/Chrome/NativeMessagingHosts` which typically should be the Mac path - but hey, may it worked (not..)

I get no error starting the application, copied the message from terminal whilst starting chrome with logging.
I pretty much went through the example google gave, adjusting paths etc.

Also went through differnt posts, but it seems no one has the same problem, or no one tries to do something similar.

Comment: Apparently renaming to `com.my.host.json` didn't work. Tried logging already, that's where I got the error message from. Edited my post - `.config` is in home.

Comment: Did you also use the new name in "name"?

Comment: Yes, the error message now displays the new name as well.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out where the problem was: 
I changed the name of my host from `my_host.json` to `com.my.host.json` and set "name" to `com.my.host` (where I firstly had the ending `.json` as well, which probably caused the problem too). Furthermore I changed `var port = chrome.runtime.connectNative("my_host.json")` in my js-file to `[...]("com.my.host")` where the ending .json was not right too. Everything works now. Thank you for your suggestions!